# how to avoid uninstantiated variables in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In prolog I have this problem about this rule, which gets proven, if the list contains an element that is `A/B`.

```
match(A,B,[H|T]) :- (H=A/B -> !; match(A,B,T)).
```

This works when I give the instantiated variables for A and B and the list. But if I give the list as a variable, then I get a list that include uninstantiated variables like `_GXXXX` which I don't want to get. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Again, it is not exactly clear what you want to achieve. Either define the results you need explicitly or give examples.

Answer (score 1):

- You can test for a variable to see if it's bound to something or not (using predicates `var/1` and `nonvar/1`)

So if for example you want the third argument to fail if it's not instantiated you'd do:

```
match(A,B,L) :- 
  nonvar(L), 
  L=[H|T], 
  (H=A/B -> !; match(A,B,T)).
```

If you are only caring about `H` in your example, then you'd do:

```
match(A,B,[H|T]) :- nonvar(H), (H=A/B -> !; match(A,B,T)).
```

Comment: in both of your cases, nonvar() fails because H or L are both not instantiated.

Comment: @omega: right. nonvar only succeeds if it's argument is not instantiated. Isn't that what you were looking for ?